# Proving tautology involving bi conditional if

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How can we prove that following proposition is a tautology with the help of logical equivalence?

$$[(r\lor{p})\rightarrow(r\lor{q})]\leftrightarrow[(r\lor(p\rightarrow{q})]$$

I can prove these types of statements but this proposition becomes too complicated and long when i try to solve it. I got help from book and online examples but those are all simple propositions not as complicated as this.

Comment: If you are in Classical Logic, just assign value true or false to the variables, and observe that you always get the same result to the left and to the rigth of the equivalence.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: That's not very welcoming.

Answer (score 2):

HINT

Use the Implication equivalence:

$$p \to q \iff \neg p \lor  q$$

So for the left side:

$$(r \lor p) \to (r \lor q) \iff \neg (r \lor p) \lor (r \lor q) \iff (\neg r \land \neg p) \lor r \lor q \iff \neg p \lor r \lor q$$

You try the right side!

Comment: I can apply rules to solve this at both ends but i reach  dead end with no way to proceed further to prove it as tautology

Comment: @KashifAmin They are not tautologies, but as long as you can rewrite them as the same expression, they are equivalent, and the coirrespoding biconditional is a tautology: $p \leftrightarrow p \iff \neg p \lor p \iff \top$

Comment: u mean like Bram28 did for the left side if i rewrite right side as same expression it will be proved?

Comment: @KashifAmin Pretty much, though if someone insists on working out the biconditional all the way to a tautology, you can use the trick I wrote in my previous comment. That is, if you write the right side as $\neg p \lor q \lor r$ as well, then you have $(\neg p \lor q \lor r) \leftrightarrow (\neg p \lor q \lor r) \iff \top$